# Filtering any email address

Tags: regex

I have an **authorizer** function which needs to check **email rules** with wildcards e.g.

- mike.*12*@*.myapp.com
- p*@*.in
- julia.admin@myapp.*

so e.g.

- peter@gmail.com => false
- peter@myapp.it => true (3rd. rule)
- pete@someapp.in => true (2nd rule)

I am a bit stuck on how to best construct a regex - or maybe there are other out of the box solutions? 
Appreciate any help!
Thanks

Comment: Regex isn't the best way to go here. The full-up e-mail standard is ***phenomenally*** complicated. What platform are you on? Odds are there's a library that does it better than a roll-your-own regex ever could.

Comment: What language/environment will you be implementing your regex in?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex `([a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]*)\@(.*?.in|.*?myapp.*)`
Demo https://regex101.com/r/D6thOr/1

Answer (score 0):

Pattern:

```
/^[^@]+@(?:(?:myapp\..+)|.+(?:\.in|myapp\.com))$/
```

[Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TDRzn8/1)

Test Cases:

- user@fail.com       `#fail`
- user@myapp.pass     `#pass`
- user@pass.in        `#pass`
- user@pass.myapp.com `#pass`

I used non-capturing groups, but you can use capture groups for pattern brevity if you wish.

I have ordered the "alternatives" with shorter mismatching patterns before longer ones for efficiency.

I also used a negated character class instead of a dot before `@` for speed reasons.